# /PathToProject/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: Internal error. Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com and attach "path_name"

Tags: ios, xcode

I came across this issue , and its not allowing me to modify Main.storyboard. Can anyone elaborate how to deal with this issue ?

And more over this is not letting any of builds to succeed. 
Attaching screenshots for reference and I have just added new code to apple's bug reporter. But for now anybody have workaround to this ?

BTW 
1)
"cmd + shift + k
AND
cmd + option + shift + k " didn't worked for me.

2) Im using xcode version 7.2

[image]

[image]